# My application is stuck on HikariPool-1 - Starting when the database is down

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

My application is getting stuck when the DB is down.  Our scenario is when the DB is down we should get data from another api.  The application is halting on

> 2023-07-26 13:00:25 [scheduling-1] INFO (c.z.h.HikariDataSource:110) - HikariPool-1 - Starting...

My properties:

```
spring:
    profiles: dv1
datasource:
    jdbc-url: ${odsdb.dbname}
    username: ${odsdb.userid}
    password: ${odsdb.passwd}
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    test-on-borrow: true  
    hikari:
        connectionTimeout: 30000
        idleTimeout: 60000
        maxLifetime: 180000
        maximumPoolSize: 30
        poolName: ns-hirakiri-pool
        connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1
        initialization-fail-fast: false

@Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = null;
        try {
            dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("Unable to get DataSource:", e);
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

public Connection getOracleDbConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) AppContext.getContext().getBean(AddressConstants.DATA_SOURCE);
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
            log.info("In getOracleDbConnection Connection:"+con);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.info("Failed to acquire a database connection: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception se) {
            log.info("Exception in getOracleDbConnection", se);
        }
        return con
    }
```

Our application is not starting. Even if I set initialization-fail-fast to "false", it is still get stuck.  Could you please provide any assistance?

How to move forward beyond hikaridatasource setup, even though the DB is down?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set the property

```
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true
```

in your application.properties file.  This should allow the fail-fast feature of spring to be overcome and proceed with application startup.